# Connecting MCP2515 with raspi

Tags: spi, arduino, can-bus

I am trying to connect mcp2515 can bus module with raspi 4b.
On using `pi@piv2:~ $ sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 125000` the terminal freezes so i downgraded my terminal to 5.4.61-v7l ,t started working after that change.
On using dmesg I found the following:

```
mcp251x spi0.0 can0: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
mcp251x spi0.0 can0: bitrate error 33.3% too high
mcp251x spi0.0 can0: bus-off
```

I had also installed can-utils package and tried to verify my connections using candump but no messages are received.
My mcp2515 works on 8Mhz, my connections are as follows:
Arduino - can module - can module - raspi, I have verified working of arduino can module via oscilloscope.
Also I am using 5v to 3.3v logic converters to connect the raspi to can bus.
I am following this page: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=141052

Comment: You should post details of what YOU did - not link to some obscure post. I don't know what "i downgraded my terminal to 5.4.61-v7l' is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

The *Forum instruction* you linked (which seems rather poor IMO) is far from clear.

I don't know what the `ip` command you listed will do but it is unlikely to have ANY impact on SPI speed, which is normally set when initialising the interface by an `ioctl` call.

I haven't used mcp2515 but the Device Tree documentation shows:-

```
dtoverlay -h mcp2515

Name:   mcp2515

Info:   Configures the MCP2515 CAN controller on spi0/1/2
        For devices on spi1 or spi2, the interfaces should be enabled
        with one of the spi1-1/2/3cs and/or spi2-1/2/3cs overlays.

Usage:  dtoverlay=mcp2515,<param>=<val>

Params: spi<n>-<m>              Configure device at spi<n>, cs<m>
                                (boolean, required)

        oscillator              Clock frequency for the CAN controller (Hz)

        speed                   Maximum SPI frequence (Hz)

        interrupt               GPIO for interrupt signal
```